# How to create a third column based on first two column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like below

| col-a | col-b |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123 |
| def | 456 |
| ghi | 789 |

I have a string str = f"https://{val1}.{val2}" and using it I want to create col-c like below

| col-a | col-b | col-c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | https://abc.123 |
| def | 456 | https://def.456 |
| ghi | 789 | https://ghi.789 |

The dataframe is big and I want to use np.where/np.select because I think .apply() function will be slow. Even with apply() I am unable to put two column values into column C .Could anyone help here?

Comment: you can use string concat `'https://' + df['col-a'].str.cat(df['col-b'].astype('str'), sep='.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method that receives the the two values you want to concatenate and returns the result:

```
import pandas as pd

# create example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 'column_2': [123, 456, 789]})

# define function to concatenate two values with an underscore
def concatenate_with_underscore(val1, val2):
    return f"https://{val1}.{val2}"

# apply function to each row of the dataframe
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: concatenate_with_underscore(row['column_1'], row['column_2']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

This produces the desired df:

```
column_1  column_2       new_column
0      abc       123  https://abc.123
1      def       456  https://def.456
2      ghi       789  https://ghi.789
```

Answer (score 1):

Using you dataframe as an input

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
 'col-a' : ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 
 'col-b' : [123, 456, 789]
     }
)
```

I tried timing a code using apply and another one using string concatenation:

```
%timeit df['col-c'] = df.apply(lambda row : f"https://{row['col-a']}.{row['col-b']}", axis = 1)
```

499 µs ± 7.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
%timeit df['col-c'] = "https://" + df['col-a'] + "." + df['col-b'].astype(str)`
```

347 µs ± 1.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Edit: added a few thousand rows

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, axis = 0)
```

now .apply() takes

```
%timeit df['col-c'] = df.apply(lambda row : f"https://{row['col-a']}.{row['col-b']}", axis = 1)
```

195 ms ± 1.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
and string concatenation takes

```
%timeit df['col-c'] = "https://" + df['col-a'] + "." + df['col-b'].astype(str)
```

11.3 ms ± 91.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Seems to me like string concatenation is the faster approach.

Comment: Nice time comparisons.  I think it will be more helpful if you compare with larger data like 1K or 1M.  That's when it gets more meaningful performance difference.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to run both the approach against larger dataset and see which gives the better performance. Can this be implemneted using np.where/np.select ?

Comment: @ChinmayNayak I don't see the need for either of those functions as we are not setting conditions for which rows to choose from, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Applying operations like `+` onto the dataframe should already be vectorised.